# [Symfony 2]Strange behaviour of orphanRemoval

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Good afternoon,

I have a problem with orphan removal in Symfony 2, on a OneToMany relationship.
When i remove a relationship between mother entity and daughter entity, the daughter entity is deleted, but strangely, the id is reused by doctrine.

The id of each remaining daughter entity will be decremented.

I wanted to show a message saying that the entity has been deleted, but i can't because the entity is not really deleted, it's just replaced by another one.

if somebody  know a solution, something to configure, or something like that.

Thanks

Edit:

Yes,

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Fonction", mappedBy="organisation", orphanRemoval=true ,cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $fonction;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Organisation", inversedBy="fonction", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="organisation_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
private $organisation;
```

Comment: Can you show the mapping configuration of all related entities?

Comment: yes, i have edited my post

Comment: lifeCycle callbacks function for debugging and perhaps more understand where is the problem